# Macbook Pro black screen during logon

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, screen

When I boot my Macbook Pro and log in, the progress bars starts scrolling. After a few seconds the screen goes completely black and then shows the progress bar again but all the rest around the progress bar is black.

I tried to reset the SMC settings but no luck. Anyone else experiencing this issue or knows how to fix it? I noticed this issue right after the upgrade to El Capitan, I don't know if it's related to that.

Specs (in case it helps troubleshooting):

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
- 2.5GHz Quad-core Intel Core i7, Turbo Boost up to 3.7GHz 16GB 1600MHz   DDR3L SDRAM
- 512GB PCIe-based Flash Storage
- Intel Iris Pro Graphics +
  AMD Radeon R9 M370X with 2GB GDDR5 memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue solved itself after a recent update to `El Capitan 10.11.4 (15E65)`. I hope the issue stays away from future versions.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same thing happen. Upgrading to El Capitan resulted in my having to erase the entire hard drive and restore using my back up! Thankfully I always back up but so far I'm not happy with ElCapitan. This upgrade has brought so many problems which are ongoing. Apple are very helpful and can offer you a number of 'fixes' so I'd recommend contacting them. Sadly for me as I mentioned erasing he hard drive was my only solution. Good luck